# C++ Returning multiple type references from function and casting them to a type that we need

Tags: c++, function, reference, return, return-type

I need a function that returns a variable, but I don't want to specify what type of variable it will return (that's something to be determined in later use).

```
// unknownType is a char, because it uses only one byte of memory
typedef char unknownType;

unknownType& func (bool typeSelector) {
    // let's say we want to return double and int type
    double dblVal = 3.5;
    int intVal = 5;

    // return type depends on typeSelector's state
    if (typeSelector == true)
        return (unknownType&)dblVal;
    else
        return (unknownType&)intVal;
}
```

and then I'll use it like this:

```
double dblVal = (double&) func(true);

std::cout << dblVal << std::endl;
std::cout << (int&) func(false);
```

The code above works just fine (if I'm not trying to return more complex object, like std::string for instance, but that's OK for my needs); I've compilated it on either linux and windows. But I'm not convinced if it's a portable solution of my problem.

My question is: is there anything in this code that could break up my program and make it useless? And how efficient is it by the terms of performance?

**EDIT: why I can't use templates here**

I've got a base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual unknownType& getValue () = 0;
};
```

And then a couple of derived classes, that are containing different type variables:

```
class DerivedDbl : public Base {
private:
    double value;
public:
    DerivedDbl (double val) : value(val) {}

    unknownType& getValue () {
        double toReturn = value;
        return (unknownType&)toReturn;
    }
};

class DerivedInt : public Base {
private:
    int value;
public:
    DerivedInt (int val) : value(val) {}

    unknownType& getValue () {
        int toReturn = value;
        return (unknownType&)toReturn;
    }
};
```

Then I've got a class, that stores derived classes and makes some operations on them:

```
class Storage {
private:
    std::vector <Base*> vec;
public:
    void operator+= (Base& obj) { vec.push_back(&obj); }

    unknownType& operator[] (int ID) {
        return vec[ID]->getValue();
    }
};
```

And I want to be able to get variable values of stored derived classes sometimes (I know which one I've add, so I know their types), but I don't think that creating separate getter methods for each one is not so elegant way to get them, and code like this looks clearer for me:

```
DerivedDbl derivedDbl(3.5);
DerivedInt derivedInt(5);

Storage storage;
storage += derivedDbl;
storage += derivedInt;

std::cout << (double&)storage[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << (int&)storage[1];
```

But maybe there's something I've missed and it's possible to do same thing using different methods (I've tried templates and didn't came up with any good ideas, you guys dissuaded void pointers, unions and structures need more memory).

Comment: _"The code above works just fine"_ I seriously doubt this. You've just hit undefined behavior. Don't use casts like that, use templates instead as mentioned.

Comment: @quantdev: the thing is, I can't. I'll edit this post in a moment to explain why.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: well, it works as expected, printing 3.5 and 5...

Comment: @Jezor Put some stack changing operation between aquisition of the reference and print the value. Then you'll see it doesnt work. Best you could do to _"make it work"_, is declaring the `int` and `double` variables used in the function `static`.

Comment: This is usually an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: so making those variables static removes undefined behavior problem? I've edited question to show what my whole problem is.

Comment: @molbdnilo: oh, you're right. I've edited my question to specify what my whole problem is.

Comment: @Jezor It might fix the UB symptom. But to be honest, your design is seriously flawed. And just mentioning about that baseclass isn't an explanation why you can't use templates. The baseclass itself could well be a template.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: it could, but I can't find a way for it to meet my expectations of one function to get every object's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a reference to a local variable. This may seem to work sometimes, but it is undefined behaviour, and will break your program horribly at some point.

If you really need a virtual function, it should probably return some sort of type hiding class (e.g. boost::any). Then you can cast the returned value to the correct type.

Alternatively you could make the function non-virtual, and cast from the base type to the appropriate derived type. The derived classes could then just return the type you actually want.

Templates could be used to facilitate this behaviour, e.g.:

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual ~Base() { }
};

template<class T>
class ValueType : public Base
{
public:

    explicit ValueType(T value): value(value) { }

    T& GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

private:

    T value;
}

struct Storage
{
    std::vector<Base*> objects;

    template<class T> 
    T& GetValue(unsigned int index)
    {
        auto derived = dynamic_cast<ValueType<T>*>(objects[index]);

        return derived->GetValue();
    }
};
```

EDIT: changed access control.

Comment: I've thought about auto specifier, but I don't have a compiler compatible with C++11 - I think I'll have to get one, thank you!

Comment: @Jezor note that `auto` is not required for the code at all, you can replace it with `ValueType<T>*` if you don't have c++11.

Comment: @user2079303 could you please edit your code to match mine? I'm trying to implement it the way I want to use it and I'm getting errors (like "‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘ValueType<double>"). I would be very thankful for that!

Comment: @Jezor you probably meant to direct the comment at the guy who wrote the answer (I know, we have quite similar usernames :) That said, error sounds like you forgot to make the inheritance public.

Comment: @Jezor As user2079303 said, structs inherit publicly by default, classes inherit privately. So if you've declared ValueType a class, you need to explicitly do `: public Base`. I've changed the code to match.